# SC.say location issue

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I am currently facing an issue with fixing the location of SC.say pop up on the screen. The default behaviour of this pop up is okay, as in , it comes at the center of the screen. But then, once you drag this pop up to a corner of the screen, then , the next time when this pop up comes , it comes at that same corner where you had dragged it to. The default behaviour of this pop up (as far as the location is concerned) changes when the user starts dragging it. Is there a way to switch back to the default behaviour irrespective of where the user drags this pop up to?? I checked the javadoc of this SC class, but couldn't get any function that would let us specify the location where this pop up should come.

SmartGWT version : 3.0
GWT version : 2.4
Browser : Firefox,IE,Chrome,Safari

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't find an easy solution to this, I think the easiest way is doing a "SC.say" by yourself.

it's very easy to replicate the built-in dialogs and then add your own functionality.

Comment: The problem is I have a lot of SC.warn , SC.ask , SC.ask dialog boxes in the application, most of them having callbacks. These callbacks are parameterised. While doing a SC.say/SC.ask/SC.warn by myself, how would I take care of those parameterised callback??

Answer (score 0):

Something could help you

```
Canvas popUp = Canvas.getById("isc_globalWarn_body");
popUp.setTop(where it was);
popUp.setLeft(.......);
popUp.setWidth(...);
etc.....
```

I find the id with the console and the Canvas static method on a post somewhere on the net I don't remember where.

Comment: What is the ID that you are trying to get by Canvas.getById("isc_globalWarn_body")?? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: It's the Id of the popup (the SC modal) Put a sc.say on the screen and start the sc console you will this element. Once you get the Id you can read original position or set a new one....